# How to Convert Buffer data to NSdata

Tags: ios, type-conversion, nsdata, openal

In my app I am using `OpenAl` to trim the audio song, now how to convert `alSourcePlay(source);` to `NSData`?

Can any one help me please?

Comment: Is it "Source" that you need to convert to NSData, what is "Source", is it a char buffer?

Comment: Check NSData.h to see how you can create NSData. You can also check NSString.h I think the answer is in the headers :)

Comment: source is of  type ALuint source;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can write the buffer data into NSDocumentDirectory  using  ExtAudioFileWrite then we will get the path of buffer we can use that path to convert into Nsdata

```
err = ExtAudioFileWrite(destinationFile, StartingFrameOffset, &theDataBuffer);
```